# Select * from table where column = $searchformdatas

Tags: php, sql

Helo, I'm trying to select a column from my SQL database.
I've put a form and got the data and then put it into a variable.

But when I try to check the equality of the condition with my SQL database, it doesn't work. I want to check the strict equality of the data stocked in the search variable so I've used =.

I don't really know how to compare the column with a variable for equality.

```
if(isset($_GET['s']) AND !empty($_GET['s']));{
    $search =  htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);

    $result = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '.$search.'' ) ;
}
```

Comment: [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work). But yeah, this code is a SQL injection and/or syntax error waiting to happen - learn to use prepared statements and parameters.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is an output filter, not an input filter. It's only useful when outputting the data into a HTML document (to help prevent XSS attacks). It has no value when used with a database query, and could in fact corrupt the data being used in the search, leading to it not finding any results.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll learn how to use properly MYSQL before continuing.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    if ($_GET['s'] != "") {
        $search =  htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);
        $result = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '".$search."' ) ;
    } else {
        // redirect to index page 
    }
}

Comment: @YasirMehmood no, that's still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and silly syntax errors, and still uses htmlspecialchars inappropriately. Please join the OP in learning to do these things properly.